# Trying to get a list of <tr>...</tr> with regular expressions in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to parse some `<tr>` from an input string in javascript. I tried to use the regular expression `(<tr[^>]*>(?:.(?!</tr>))*.</tr>)*`. But I only get the last `<tr>`. See also [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gurumusch/T66ph/4/).

```
$("#container").append(content);

parts = new RegExp("^(.*tbody[^>]*>)(.*)(</tbody>.*)").exec(content);
table = parts[1] + parts[3];
rowString = parts[2];
$("#rowString").text(rowString);

// This is the interesting row:
rows = new RegExp("(<tr[^>]*>(?:.(?!</tr>))*.</tr>)*").exec(rowString);

$("#count").text(rows.length - 1 + " row(s) found");

for (rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < rows.length; rowIndex += 1) {
    rowListItem = $("<li></li>");
    rowListItem.text(rows[rowIndex]);
    $("#list").append(rowListItem);
}
```

**Update**

Thanks for your answers. I will do it the way DhruvPathak suggested. Unforunately jQuery is no Option because it has an "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" with big tables. Although I won't need it any more does anybody know what's wrong with my regular expression?

Comment: This doesn't look like a job for regex, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Why are you writing your own html parser when the browser has a perfectly good one already available to you from within Javascript?

Comment: HTML & Regex is usually a bad combo http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html.

Comment: It is part of a library for data virtualization. Especially IE is extremly slow when it hat lot of data in its HTML. And I have to deal with tons of table data...

Comment: @Andreas, my example below actually does more in memory than yours does. Being HTML wont affect it unless it's actually modifying the DOM thats already appended. In my example below, I create the entire list in memory and then append it at once rather than append item by item to the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead set this string as innerHTML of a node created by document.createElement, and then use getElementsByTagName.

eg: http://jsfiddle.net/5JwXr/

```
var parentCont = document.createElement('div');
parentCont.innerHTML = content ;
x = parentCont.getElementsByTagName('tr');
alert(x.length);
```

Comment: IE is really slow with many elements. That's why I want to do the work in memory only. But I will try that.

Comment: @Andreas I hope you don't mean what I think by that...Even on an older browser, using a native browser function for something is usually going to be faster than implementing it yourself in a scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete redo of your code with a working result... using jquery instead of regex (as I noticed you are using jquery in part): http://jsfiddle.net/T66ph/8/

```
$("#container").append(content);
$tbody = $(content).find("tbody");
$("#rowString").text($tbody.html());
$rows = $tbody.find("tr");
$("#count").text($rows.length + " row(s) found");
$temp = $("<div>");
$rows.each( function() {
    $temp.append($("<li>").text(this.outerHTML));
});
//adding the DOM all at once instead of little by little will help performance
$("#list").append($temp.html());
```